# How can I define a node to tasktracker of one mapreduce cluster and Jobtracker of second mapreduce cluster?

Tags: hadoop

Suppose there are 3nodes:Slave1,Slave2 and Slave3.
*Slave1 and Slave2 are making one mapreduce cluster.And Slave2 and Slave3 are making another mapreduce cluster.*

- To make first cluster Slave1(JobTracker) and Slave2(tasktracker ) did following:
- **ON Slave1 MACHINE**
  `i) conf/masters
  Slave1
  ii)conf/slaves
  Slave2
  iii)conf/mapred-site.xml
  <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>Slave1:54311</value>
  </property>`
- **ON Slave2 MACHINE**
  `i)conf/mapred-site.xml
  <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>Slave1:54311</value>`
- To make Second cluster Slave2(JobTracker) and Slave3(tasktracker ) did following
- **ON Slave2 MACHINE**
  `i) conf/masters
  Slave2
  ii)conf/slaves
  Slave3
  iii)conf/mapred-site.xml
  <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>Slave2:54311</value>
  </property>`
  *NOW WHAT SHOULD BE PROPERTY TO RUN JOBTRACKER ON Slave2 FOR SECONDCLUSTER ??*
- **ON Slave3 MACHINE**
  `i)conf/mapred-site.xml
  <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>Slave2:54311</value>`

I hope I made my point clear. any suggestions !!!

Comment: Interested in your use case for why you'd want to do this?

Comment: Actually I am working with some cluster resource managment company.so I want multiple mapreduce cluster setups with "efficient" resources manangment...

Comment: In my opinion, if you still only have a single HDFS instance behind both clusters, you're better off trying to implement a custom scheduler to manage resources, and have a single Job Tracker

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes..you are right.I have a single HDFS cluster ( or say instances ) behind both clusters..
So any suggestion for my problem that is described above ??

Comment: with your current setup, have you tried to run start-mapred.sh on Slave2?

Comment: @ChrisWhite
I tried to configure two conf/mapred-site.xml on slave2, one for MapReduce Cluster1 (which reports to jobtracker Slave1) and second for MapReduce Cluster2 (which acts as Jobtracker ). Both conf/mapred-site.xml are kept in two different directories and also copied conf/hadoop-env.sh file to both directories and made corresponding changes in $HADOOP_CONF_DIR variable.
_But Now main problem is when I tried to stop MapReduce cluster2 then it also stopped tasktracker i.e slave2 of MapReduce cluster1 along with cluster2 instances._

Comment: Any suggestion how to setup a node to be tasktracer of multiple clusters means **what will be settings for one node and multiple tasktrackers !!**